# Scons/Doom 3 compile error on ubuntu

Tags: linux, compilation

When I run the scons command from the neo folder in my extracted source tree, I get the following output:

```
nroach44@ASUS-P5G43T-U1110:~/Source/doom3engine/neo$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Loading build configuration from site.conf:
  BUILD_GAMEPAK='0'
  JOBS='1'
  DEDICATED='0'
  SILENT='0'
  GL_HARDLINK='0'
  ID_MCHECK='2'
  BUILD_ROOT='build'
  ALSA='1'
  CC='gcc'
  TARGET_D3XP='1'
  TARGET_CORE='1'
  BUILD='debug'
  TARGET_GAME='1'
  TARGET_MONO='0'
  BASEFLAGS=''
  CXX='g++'
  NOCURL='0'
  DEBUG_MEMORY='0'
  IDNET_HOST=''
  LIBC_MALLOC='1'
  ID_NOLANADDRESS='0'
  TARGET_DEMO='0'
AttributeError: 'SConsEnvironment' object has no attribute 'M4':
  File "/home/nroach44/Source/doom3engine/neo/SConstruct", line 422:
    SConscript( g_build + '/core/glimp/sys/scons/SConscript.gl' )
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 614:
    return method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 551:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 260:
    exec _file_ in call_stack[-1].globals
  File     "/home/nroach44/Source/doom3engine/neo/build/debug/core/glimp/sys/scons/SConscript.gl", line 69:
gl_env.M4( i_m4, i_m4 + '.m4' )
```

I can't tell if it's missing something, not referenced something or what. This does happen from a fresh extract into a new folder too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing the `m4` macro package -- perhaps `scons` is looking for it and this is its way of reporting missing tools?

Comment: Would that be through apt-get?

Comment: Just found it through apt-cache. I'll report back.

Answer (score 10):

> sudo apt-get install m4

that fixed problem for me...

then I got:

> scons: done reading SConscript files. scons: Building targets ...
>   scons: building associated VariantDir targets: build/debug/core/glimp
>   build/debug/core build/debug/game build/debug/d3xp g++ -o
>   build/debug/d3xp/d3xp/AF.os -c -fPIC -pipe -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas
>   -fmessage-length=0 -fpermissive -fvisibility=hidden -m32 -g -O1 -D_DEBUG -fno-strict-aliasing -D_D3XP -DCTF -DGAME_DLL d3xp/AF.cpp In file included from d3xp/../idlib/precompiled.h:142:0,
>                    from d3xp/AF.cpp:29: d3xp/../idlib/../renderer/qgl.h:51:19: fatal error: GL/gl.h: No such
>   file or directory compilation terminated. scons: ***
>   [build/debug/d3xp/d3xp/AF.os] Error 1 scons: building terminated
>   because of errors.

fixed by:

> sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev

then got:

> In file included from
>   build/debug/core/glimp/sys/linux/glimp_dlopen.cpp:3:0:
>   ./sys/linux/local.h:40:38: fatal error: X11/extensions/xf86vmode.h: No
>   such file or directory compilation terminated. scons: ***
>   [build/debug/core/glimp/sys/linux/glimp_dlopen.o] Error 1 scons:
>   building terminated because of errors.

fixed by:

> sudo apt-get install libxxf86vm-dev

then got:

> In file included from openal/stubs.cpp:29:0:
>   openal/../sound/snd_local.h:44:19: fatal error: AL/al.h: No such file
>   or directory compilation terminated.

fixed by:

> sudo apt-get install libopenal-dev

then got:

> In file included from sys/linux/sound.cpp:42:0:
>   sys/linux/sound.h:90:28: fatal error: alsa/asoundlib.h: No such file
>   or directory compilation terminated. scons: ***
>   [build/debug/core/sys/linux/sound.o] Error 1 scons: building
>   terminated because of errors.

fixed by:

> sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev

then got:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   scons: *** [build/debug/core/sys/scons/doom] Error 1 scons: building
>   terminated because of errors.

fixed by:

> sudo apt-get install g++-multilib gcc-multilib
>   sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev

and finally:

> Install file: "build/debug/core/sys/scons/doom" as "doom.x86" Install
>   file: "build/debug/game/sys/scons/libgame.so" as "gamex86-base.so"
>   Install file: "build/debug/d3xp/sys/scons/libgame.so" as
>   "gamex86-d3xp.so" scons: done building targets.

Please also check:
http://mapopa.blogspot.com/2011/11/building-doom3-gpl-code-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: +1 in addition to what you recommended, i am running into errors compiling curl: http://lists.gobolinux.org/pipermail/gobolinux-users/2004-December/000370.html (i'm getting the same error) -- this website http://wiki.iodoom3.org/Downloading_and_Compiling_under_Linux recommends running `scons NOCURL=1`, so i'm trying that..